# Create Index with single drop down list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-select

I want to create an index page that starts with a single drop down list. Once the user selects a category, and second drop down list will appear (via an Ajax call) that will allow the user select which model item to edit. Using the code in my controller and view below, however, I am getting the following error

`The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[Monet.Models.DropDownValues]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Monet.Models.DropDownValues'.`

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //redirect if security is not met. 
        if (!Security.IsAdmin(User)) return RedirectToAction("Message", "Home", new { id = 1 });

        var dropDownValues =  (from b in db.DropDownValues
                              orderby b.Model
                              select b.Model).Distinct();

        ViewBag.CategoryOptions = new SelectList(dropDownValues, "Model", "Model");

        return View(db.DropDownValues.ToList());
    }
```

**View**

```
@model Monet.Models.DropDownValues

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Monet Administration";
}

<h2>Monet Administration</h2>
Update values for drop down boxes

<div>
    <span style="float: left;">
        <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Categories", (SelectList)ViewBag.CategoryOptions, "")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Model)
        </div>
    </span>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your View expects a single instance of `Monet.Models.DropDownValues` and you're passing it a `List<Monet.Models.DropDownValues>`

You should either pass a single item from the controller (if that makes sense):

```
return View(db.DropDownValues.ToList().First());
```

or change your Model type in the View:

```
@model List<Monet.Models.DropDownValues>
```